# dsPIC - do I lose Port functionality on a CN pin?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, software

I'm testing some code with a [dsPIC33FJ32MC102](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000652f.pdf) on MPLAB X with XC16. I've got some pull up dip switches connected to RB0-RB2 which I want to use to switch LEDs connected to RB7-RB9. I can get the LEDs to light up manually with a LATB = 0x380 instruction, however when I flick the switches nothing happens. I've tested the switches and wiring and verified that it's all correct, and as far as I can tell my code is right. Based on all the datasheets I've read, I should still get port I/O on a CN input, so why isn't this working?

Here's my code (in a primordial state, so all the settings are still verbose):

```
// DSPIC33FJ32MC102 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

#define FOSC    (3686400ULL)
#define FCY     (FOSC/2)

#include <xc.h>
#include <libpic30.h>

// CONFIG2
#pragma config POSCMOD = NONE           // Primary Oscillator Select (Primary oscillator disabled)
#pragma config ALTI2C = OFF             // Alternate I2C pins (I2C mapped to SDA1/SCL1)
#pragma config LPOL = ON                // Motor Control PWM Low Side Polarity bit (PWM module low side output pins have active-high output polarity)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON             // IOLOCK Protection (Allow Only One Re-configuration)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = ON            // Primary Oscillator Output Function (OSC2 pin has digital I/O function)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor (Clock switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor are disabled)
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIVN          // Oscillator Mode (Internal Fast RC (FRC) with divide by N)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WDTWIN25        // Watchdog Window Select (Watchdog Window is 25% of WDT period)
#pragma config PWMPIN = ON              // Motor Control PWM Module Pin Mode bit (PWM module pins controlled by PORT register at device Reset)
#pragma config PWMLOCK = ON             // PWM Lock Enable (Certain PWM registers may only be written after key sequence)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Internal External Switch Over Mode (Start-up device with FRC, then automatically switch to user-selected oscillator source when ready)

// CONFIG1
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // WDT Prescaler (Prescaler ratio of 1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON              // PLL Lock Enable (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable (Watchdog timer enabled/disabled by user software)
#pragma config ICS = PGD3               // Comm Channel Select (Communicate on PGEC3/PGED3)
#pragma config HPOL = ON                // Motor Control PWM High Side Polarity bit (PWM module high side output pins have active-high output polarity)
#pragma config GWRP = ON                // General Code Segment Write Protect (Writes to program memory are disabled)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Segment Code Protection (General Segment Code protect is disabled)

char t1ctr = 0;
unsigned short PAin     = 0;
unsigned short PAout    = 0;
unsigned short PBin     = 0;
unsigned short PBout    = 0;

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, __auto_psv__)) _T1Interrupt(void){
    t1ctr++;
    if(t1ctr==40){              //after 1 second
        t1ctr = 0;
        LATAbits.LATA1 ^= 1;    //toggle the LED
    }

    IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;
}

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, __auto_psv__)) _CNInterrupt(void){
    PBin = PORTB;       //Read the port
    PBin &= 0x0007;     //get only the inputs
    PBout = PBin << 7;  //move them out to the outputs
    LATB = PBout;       
    IFS1bits.CNIF = 0;
}

void main(void){

//OSCILLATOR CONFIGS
    CLKDIVbits.ROI      = 0;
    CLKDIVbits.FRCDIV   = 0b001; //3.68MHz
    CLKDIVbits.DOZEN    = 0;
    OSCTUNbits.TUN      = 0b00000;
    OSCCONbits.CLKLOCK  = 1;

//PERIPHERAL CONFIGS
    //enable only Timer 1, PWM, and ADC
    PMD1bits.T5MD       = 1;
    PMD1bits.T4MD       = 1;
    PMD1bits.T3MD       = 1;
    PMD1bits.T2MD       = 1;
    PMD1bits.T1MD       = 0;
    PMD1bits.PWM1MD     = 0;
    PMD1bits.I2C1MD     = 1;
    PMD1bits.U1MD       = 1;
    PMD1bits.SPI1MD     = 1;
    PMD1bits.AD1MD      = 0;

    //disable Input Capture/Output Compare
    PMD2bits.IC3MD      = 1;
    PMD2bits.IC2MD      = 1;
    PMD2bits.IC1MD      = 1;
    PMD2bits.OC2MD      = 1;
    PMD2bits.OC1MD      = 1;

    //disable comparator and RTCC
    PMD3bits.CMPMD      = 1;
    PMD3bits.RTCCMD     = 1;

    //disable CTMU
    PMD4bits.CTMUMD     = 1;

//PORT CONFIGS
    //disable open drains on Port A, B
    ODCA                = 0x0000;
    ODCB                = 0x0000;

    //Enable AN0 only; digital I/O on all other pins
    AD1PCFGL            = 0x0001;
    TRISA               = 0x0001;   //AN0 must be input for ADC to work right

    //Port B
    TRISB               = 0x0007;   //In on 0,1,2
    LATB                = 0x0000;
    //IFS3bits.FLTA1IF    = 0;        //must be pulled up externally  
    //IFS4bits.FLTB1IF    = 0;

    //Clear outputs
    LATA                = 0x0000;
    //LATB already clear

    //Enable CN4,5,6 (PortB) and corresponding interrupts
    CNEN1bits.CN4IE     = 1;
    CNEN1bits.CN5IE     = 1;
    CNEN1bits.CN6IE     = 1; //pullups are disabled on reset
    IEC1bits.CNIE       = 1; 

    IPC4bits.CNIP       = 0b010; // Change on bus is priority 6 of 7

    //Set UART input to RP8 (17), output ot RP9 (18)
    /*
    RPINR18bits.U1RXR   = 0b01000;
    RPOR4bits.RP9R      = 0b00011;
    */


//TIMER CONFIGS
    //setup Timer1
    T1CONbits.TCS       = 0;        //Use internal clock
    T1CONbits.TCKPS     = 00;       //Prescale 1; ticks at 1.843200MHz
    T1CONbits.TSIDL     = 1;        //Disable during idle
    PR1                 = 46080;    //46080 ticks = 25ms to ovf
    T1CONbits.TGATE     = 0;        //dunno if this should be 0 or 1.
    IPC0bits.T1IP       = 0b001;    //Lowest priority interrupt
    IEC0bits.T1IE       = 1;        //Enable interrupts
    T1CONbits.TON       = 1;        //Turn on

    LATB = 0x0380;
    while(1){
    }
}
```

Comment: You might try initializing PORTB to 0x0007; I always set ports bits that are inputs to 1.

Comment: Have you got pull-down resistors on the DIP switch bank?

Comment: @tcrosley: That would be silly.  If you keep a pin set as input (TRIS bit set), then whatever you write to the PORT or LAT bits for the pin are completely irrelevant.

Comment: I got one of the switches to work by changing the main loop to poll the switches and caught an error with the ADC asserting control over the pins, however something else is blocking RB0 and 1

Comment: @OlinLathrop --Sorry, got micros confused.  That is what is required on Silicon Labs 8051's.  (Obviously they have different port logic.)  I divide my time between PICs, HCS08's, and 8051s (prefer PICs of course).

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I do. The inputs never float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. The ADC on this dsPIC is active low, not active high, so setting the configuration to 0x0001 turned all ADCs on except the one I needed, blocking the critical input. I inverted the configuration setting and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Show how exactly the switches are connected to the port pins.  If you did the normal thing of connecting each switch between a I/O pin and ground, then you probably forgot to turn on the internal pullups for those pins.

Comment: The pins are pulled up and down externally. http://i.imgur.com/dnrfyzX.png